# Совет по выбору ПО для удаленного доступа к ПК

Tags: администрирование, админка

Есть маленькая компания, в ней 12 пк под win8.1, которыми нужно изредка управлять удаленно. Конечно нужно лицензирование, чтобы проблем с законом не было. На какой продукт стоит обратить внимание? Teamviewer хорош, но может есть какое-то бесплатное или open source решение, ну или просто более дешевое?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VPN-сервер(например [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/)) на маршрутизаторе, сервере, или просто постоянно работающей машине в сети + VNC-сервера на машинах(например [TigerVNC](http://tigervnc.org/)) - вот вам и вполне себе удобное решение с открытым исходным кодом для маленьких компаний.

Правда придется пройтись, да установить/настроить всё самостоятельно(либо развернуть на машинах через AD), а не "скину ссылку пользователю, да оно как-нибудь само настроится и заработает"(как в TeamViewer).